# Hover and onClick image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 different images being used as anchors. I am looking to have an image replace on hover and keep that image throughout the click action. Then keep that new image until another image with the same class is clicked. I am not sure exactly how to achieve this function. The Code is below. Thank you guys in advance.

HTML

```
 <img class="year" id="yr60" src="/images/1960-a.jpg" style="height:24px;margin-left:132px;position:relative;top:-150px;width:96px;" /> 
 <img class="year" id="yr70" src="/images/1970-a.jpg" style="height:24px;margin-left:55px;position:relative;top:-150px;width:96px;" /> 
 <img class="year" id="yr80" src="/images/1980-a.jpg" style="height:24px;margin-left:55px;position:relative;top:-150px;width:96px;" /> 
 <img class="year" id="yr90" src="/images/1990-a.jpg" style="height:24px;margin-left:55px;position:relative;top:-150px;width:96px;" /> 
 <img class="year" id="yr20" src="/images/2000-a.jpg" style="height:24px;margin-left:55px;position:relative;top:-150px;width:96px;" />
```

The hover image for each are src="/images/1960-h.jpg" | src="/images/1970-h.jpg" | src="/images/1980-h.jpg" etc.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this as sort of a brain exercise, so even though I know you didn't exactly follow the rules I hope you get some use out of it. http://jsfiddle.net/8GPNP/

```
function replaceold(sel) {
$(sel).each(function() {
    oldvalue = $(this).attr("src").replace("-h", "-a");
    $(this).attr("src", oldvalue);
});
}
$("img").on("mouseenter",function(e) {
   newvalue = $(this).attr("src").replace("-a", "-h");
   $(this).attr("src", newvalue);
});

$("img").on("click",function() {
    $("img").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("img").on("mouseleave",function() {
    //reset all src
    replaceold('img:not(.selected)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use src [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

In `each` `loop` you can change the `src`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            $(this).attr("src", "newSrc");
        });
        .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "OldSrc");
        });});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this with css

```
img.year:before {
    content: '';
}
img.year:hover, img.year:active, img.year:focus {
    content: '';
}
img#yr60:hover:before, img#yr60:active:before, img#yr60:focus:before {
    content: url("/images/1960-h.jpg");
}
img#yr70:hover:before, img#yr70:active:before, img#yr70:focus:before {
    content: url("/images/1970-h.jpg");
}
img#yr80:hover:before, img#yr80:active:before, img#yr80:focus:before {
    content: url("/images/1980-h.jpg");
}
img#yr90:hover:before...
```

something like that should work.